# What is a "rotated" basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, vector-spaces

My [text](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs191/sp12/notes/chap1&2.pdf) (p. 19) introduces the concept of a "rotated" basis without explanation. What properties or characteristics of a basis make it "rotated" with respect to another? What operation on one basis produces a basis that is rotated with respect to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, it means they differ by a unitary transformation of $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Comment: Is there a more elementary way to state that, or break it down? It seems to me (linear algebra is a distant and dimming memory; I'm not sure what "unitary transformation" means, for example) that if you start with a set of "orthonormal" vectors, $S$ in $\mathbb{C}^n$, then *any* other such set of vectors will be "rotated" with respect to $S$. Is that right?

Comment: Correct, any 2 orthonormal bases differ by a unitary transformation.  This follows directly from the definition of unitary: $UU^* = I$, where $U^*$ is the conjugate transpose of $U$.

Comment: So in contexts like my text, "rotated" pretty much means "any", since we're generally assuming "basis" $\equiv$ 
"orthonormal basis"?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: And just to be sure, even a "reflection" is a "rotation" in this sense (e.g. since $X\equiv \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ is a unitary transformation). Right?

Comment: Yes.  Unlike the case of the orthogonal group over $\mathbb{R}$, which splits into "rotations" of determinant 1 and "reflections" of determinant -1, the unitary group over $\mathbb{C}$ is connected, so there is no hard split.  The determinant of a unitary matrix can be any number $e^{i \theta}$ on the unit circle.  However, you could limit yourself to the *special unitary transformations* of determinant 1, in certain contexts.  This would exclude the "stretching" unitary transformations like multiplication by $e^{i \theta}$.